# ActiveRecord `readonly? = true` is preventing `destroy`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, readonly, destroy

According to all the documentation and tutorials I've found, defining the following method in my ActiveRecord subclass (`AuthenticationToken`) should prevent saving changes to an existing record, but not prevent it from being created or destroyed:

```
def readonly?
    !new_record?
end
```

However, calling `token.destroy` throws `"AuthenticationToken is marked as readonly"`. For now I am using `token.delete`, which is acceptable because the model has no children, but I'd like to be able to use destroy. I'm using Rails 4.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding

```
before_destroy { true }
```

would allow you to destroy the object.

Comment: @TGPrankster can you put `binding.pry` into `before_destroy` and see, if that is being called?

Answer (score 0):

Use [delete](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-delete) instead, it will be able to delete records marked as readonly

Comment: As a word of caution: this bypasses callbacks and association checks